# best algorithm for 3D peak search

Tags: multivariable-calculus, signal-processing

Good morning,

I have a 3D data cube of 3 independant and complex variables.

I am looking for an algorithm (with a realistic computationnal time) to do 3D peak detection on my data.

My current method consists in 2D peaks detection using 2 variables and then for each peak check if it is also a peak in the third dimension.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good afternoon here...

Comment: It is true that ther are people from all around the world here. I should have said 'Hello' but good afternoon anyway @JeanMarie

Comment: Besides, you should give an example, because just the first sentence is hard to understand. For example do you mean complex in the sense $z \in \mathbb{C}$, If yes which kind of data is it (phase data ?) ?

Comment: Yes, I mean complex in the sense z∈C. I work on radar data. The 3 variables are _Range, Speed_ and _Azimuth_

Comment: Just wondering if you found an answer to your question @B.Sarah?